# Meaning of get/getting engaged

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-meaning

What is the meaning of and difference between the following sentences?

> We get engaged.
>
> We are getting engaged.

Answer (score 1):

If by 'engaged' you mean 'betrothed' or 'pledged to marry', then the usual way of expressing this is:

> We **got** engaged last week.    {Past tense}
>
> We **are** now engaged.          {Present tense}
>
> We **will get** engaged sometime next year.   {Future tense}

It is possible to use 'get engaged' in a sentence, but not in the way that you did, e.g.

> We want to **get engaged** next year.
>
> When did you **get engaged**?
>
> I want to have a big party when we **get engaged**.
>
> Do you think they will ever **get engaged**?